# Не срабатывает default_factory в defaultdict

Tags: python, dict

Всем привет. Есть такой кусок кода:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

name_on_id = {
    42: 'Кирилл',
    59: 'Игорь',
}

def default_func():
    return "Инкогнито"

test = defaultdict(default_func)
test.update(name_on_id)

def foo(user_id):
    name = test.get(user_id)
    return f'Привет, {name}'


print(foo(42)) # Привет, Кирилл 
print(foo(1))  # Привет, None 
print(test[1]) # Инкогнито
```

Хотел попрактиковаться в работе с несуществующими значениями в словарях и после дефолтных параметров метода `get` перешёл к `defaultdict`.
Ожидал, что при вызове `foo` с 1 в консоль попадёт "Привет, Инкогнито", но получаю "Привет, None", хотя если напрямую обратиться к `test` по несуществующему ключу, то всё работает. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Потому что defaultdict меняет только поведение `test[user_id]` (то есть метода \_\_getitem\_\_), а поведение метода get никак не меняется

Comment: @andreymal, большое спасибо